# SPI over GPIO on UWP

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, gpio, spi, windows-iot-core-10

I try to integrate max7219 with UWP application running on Raspberry Pi 3.
max7219 connected to follow pins:

- 40 (GPIO21) - Clock
- 38 (GPIO20) - Data
- 36 (GPIO16) - CS

The native SPI ports: 19, 21, 23, 24, 26 are busy with touchpad.
I didn't found how to configure .NET `Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice` to use GPIO ports, so I ported `shiftOut` from Arduino as follow:

```
    private void shiftOut(BitOrder aBitOrder, byte val)
    {
        if (aBitOrder == BitOrder.LSBFIRST) {
            for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                GpioPinValue __val = (val & (1 << i)) == 0x0 ? 
                    GpioPinValue.Low : 
                    GpioPinValue.High;

                _data_pin.Write(__val);
            }
        } else {
            for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                GpioPinValue __val = (val & (1 << (7 - i))) == 0x0 ? 
                    GpioPinValue.Low : 
                    GpioPinValue.High;

                _data_pin.Write(__val);
            }
        }

        _clock_pin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        _clock_pin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
    }
```

In the past the project was running on Arduino Avr and used GPIO ports via `shiftOut` function.

Now, I run the project over Raspberry Pi 3. I provide follow data to the chip:

```
{ 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x1, 0x01, 0x01 },
{ 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
{ 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x1, 0x01, 0x01 }
```

but the LEDs on the dial (which managed by max7219) **are flickering in chaotic way**.
Basing on the chip's data sheet I think, that the problem is - the frequency of the Raspberry processor.

[image: max7219 timing]
While Arduino runs with approximately 50 MHz, the Rasbpery Pi 3 runs with 1.4 GHz.
The values such as Tcl, Tch etc. were in the acceptance range on Arduino, may be some thing around microsecond, but on Raspberry it may be 1 or 2 nanoseconds.

The next problem, is - I can not insert short enough pause between writing, the minimal pause can be a millisecond, and I thing it too much for SPI standards:

```
_clock_pin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
Task.Delay(-1).Wait(1);  
_clock_pin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
```

The other problem, I run the project with Visual Studio 2015, so I can not use Nuget libraries as RaspberrySharp and other.
What can be solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two native SPIs on Raspberry Pi 3, you can use SPI1:

[image]

Code sample of using SPI1:

```
// Use chip select line CS0
var settings = new SpiConnectionSettings(0);
// Set clock to 10MHz 
settings.ClockFrequency = 10000000;

// Get a selector string that will return our wanted SPI controller
string aqs = SpiDevice.GetDeviceSelector("SPI1");

// Find the SPI bus controller devices with our selector string
var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

// Create an SpiDevice with our selected bus controller and Spi settings
using (SpiDevice device = await SpiDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings))
{
    byte[] writeBuf = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
    device.Write(writeBuf);
}
```